# Sequences of Coefficients in $a p^i + b q^j = 1$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $p$ and $q$ be different primes. Then for all positive integers $i$ and $j$ there exists integers $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$ with

$$ a_{ij} p^i + b_{ij} q^j = 1.$$

What is known about the sequence $\left((a_{ij},b_{ij})\right)_{i,j}$ of coefficients? Is there an explicit formula for calculating them? If no, is there a subsequence $i_k$, $j_k$  of indices, for which the sequence of coefficients $a_{i_kj_k}$ and $b_{i_kj_k}$ are known?

Comment: For every (i,j) pair there a lot of pairs (a,b) satisfacting this equation, so are there any other restrictions? Also, how explicit formula for them should be? Is something like $a_{ii}=p^{-i}\mod q^i$ acceptable?

Comment: $b_{ij}$, for a fixed $j$, converges $p$-adically to $q^{-j}$. What else would you like ?

Comment: $a_{ij} = p^{i(q^{j-1}(q-1)-1)}$. Too localized.

Comment: Euclid's algorithm gives an algorithm for computing these things. Is a "formula" different from an algorithm? If so, can you define "formula"?

Comment: Let's make it $a_{ij}p^i-b_{ij}q^j=1$. Then there's a unique solution with $0\lt a_{ij}\lt q^j$ and $0\lt b_{ij}\lt p^i$. Conceivably, one could say something about this solution that OP would find satisfactory, though I doubt it. 

Comment: Here's an experiment. Calculate $a_n$ and $b_n$ for $a_n3^n-b_n2^n=1$ for $n=1$, $n=2$, etc., stopping when you find the kind of pattern you're looking for, or when you give up hope. You may learn more about the problem that way than from the answers we are giving. 

Answer (score 1):

At least some things can be said. Say we are looking at $a_{ij}p^i-b_{ij}q^j=1$ with $0\lt a_{ij}\lt q^j$ and $0\lt b_{ij}\lt p^i$. Then for fixed $j$ there are at most $q^j-q^{j-1}$ possible values for  $a_{ij}.$ These values cycle periodically with each completely determined by the previous. (the period is likely to be too large to be practical though) and knowing any $a_{ij}$ yields the corresponding $b_{ij}$ Furthermore, $a_{0j}=1$ and $b_{0j}=0$. Similar remarks holds for fixed $i$ with $j$ allowed to grow. None of this is very useful computationally.

To partially avoid subscripts for the moment, let $a_{ij}p^i-b_{ij}q^j=1$ and also $up^{i+1}-vq^j=1$. Since  $(up)p^i-vq^j=1$ we know that $up=a_{ij}+mq^j$ and $v=b_{i,j}-mp^i$ where $0 \le m \le p-1$ is the unique value making $\frac{a_{ij}+mq^j}{p}$ an integer. For example, in the simplest case of $p=2$ , we either have $a_{i+1,j}=a_{ij}/2$ and $b_{i+1,j}=b_{i,j}$ or else $a_{i+1,j}=(a_{ij}+q^j)/2$ and $b_{i+1,j}=b_{i,j}-2^i$ according as $a_{ij}$ is even or odd.

Also, we only need that $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime.